VS code function parameter suggestion hide
I am a new user of the VS code editor. I have used " WordPress Snippets" extension to get WordPress suggestions. It's working well and it's giving me the suggestion perfectly. But I don't want to add the function parameter when I write a function and hit the enter button. because I have another vs code extension that name is " Phpstorm parameter hints " to get hints when I write the function parameter. so, is there any way to not automatically write the function parameter when I write a new function?
Note: I want to get the suggestion. just only remove the parameter.
example: add_action( $hook_name:string, $callback:callable, $priority:integer, $accepted_args:integer );
I don't want this. " $hook_name:string, $callback:callable, $priority:integer, $accepted_args:integer "

